# PDF Compression with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am currently trying to recompress a pdf that has already been created, I am trying to find a way to recompress the images that are in the document, to reduce the file size.

I have been trying to do this with the DataLogics PDE and iTextSharp libraries but I can not find a way to do the stream recompression of the items.

I have though about looping over the xobjects and getting the images and then dropping the DPI down to 96 or using the libjpeg C# implimentation to change the quality of the image but getting it back into the pdf stream seems to always end up, with memory corruption or some other issue.

Any samples will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296667/pdftk-compression-option you could also use ImageMagick

Comment: as it's .NET, @Guillaume problem is talking about http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/

Comment: @balexandre The problem is not resampling the images, but actually getting the images back into the pdf stream, you cannot save the images to disk as it will create issues with transparency etc..

Comment: but you can save it into a `MemoryStream` and then back to the document as appending it or adding a page with that `Stream` correct?

Comment: @balexandre Well yes but I need to re-inject it into the stream and not work with the bitmaps.

Answer (score 11):

iText and iTextSharp have some methods for replacing indirect objects. Specifically there's `PdfReader.KillIndirect()` which does what it says and `PdfWriter.AddDirectImageSimple(iTextSharp.text.Image, PRIndirectReference)` which you can then use to replace what you killed off.

In pseudo C# code you'd do:

```
var oldImage = PdfReader.GetPdfObject();
var newImage = YourImageCompressionFunction(oldImage);
PdfReader.KillIndirect(oldImage);
yourPdfWriter.AddDirectImageSimple(newImage, (PRIndirectReference)oldImage);
```

Converting the raw bytes to a .Net image can be tricky, I'll leave that up to you or you can search here. Mark has a [good description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5953834/231316). Also, technically PDFs don't have a concept of DPI, that's for printers mostly. [See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245450/231316) for more on that.

Using the method above your compression algorithm can actually do two things, physically shrink the image as well as apply JPEG compression. When you physically shrink the image and add it back it will occupy the same amount of space as the original image but with less pixels to work with. This will get you what you consider to be DPI reduction. The JPEG compression speaks for itself.

Below is a full working C# 2010 WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0. It takes an existing JPEG on your desktop called "LargeImage.jpg" and creates a new PDF from it. Then it opens the PDF, extracts the image, physically shrinks it to 90% of the original size, applies 85% JPEG compression and writes it back to the PDF. See the comments in the code for more of an explanation. The code needs lots more null/error checking. Also looks for `NOTE` comments where you'll need to expand to handle other situations.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Our working folder
            string workingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            //Large image to add to sample PDF
            string largeImage = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "LargeImage.jpg");
            //Name of large PDF to create
            string largePDF = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "Large.pdf");
            //Name of compressed PDF to create
            string smallPDF = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "Small.pdf");

            //Create a sample PDF containing our large image, for demo purposes only, nothing special here
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(largePDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                using (Document doc = new Document()) {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                        doc.Open();

                        iTextSharp.text.Image importImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(largeImage);
                        doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, importImage.Width, importImage.Height));
                        doc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        doc.NewPage();
                        doc.Add(importImage);

                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Now we're going to open the above PDF and compress things

            //Bind a reader to our large PDF
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(largePDF);
            //Create our output PDF
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(smallPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                //Bind a stamper to the file and our reader
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs)) {
                    //NOTE: This code only deals with page 1, you'd want to loop more for your code
                    //Get page 1
                    PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(1);
                    //Get the xobject structure
                    PdfDictionary resources = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(page.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES));
                    PdfDictionary xobject = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(resources.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT));
                    if (xobject != null) {
                        PdfObject obj;
                        //Loop through each key
                        foreach (PdfName name in xobject.Keys) {
                            obj = xobject.Get(name);
                            if (obj.IsIndirect()) {
                                //Get the current key as a PDF object
                                PdfDictionary imgObject = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
                                //See if its an image
                                if (imgObject.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.IMAGE)) {
                                    //NOTE: There's a bunch of different types of filters, I'm only handing the simplest one here which is basically raw JPG, you'll have to research others
                                    if (imgObject.Get(PdfName.FILTER).Equals(PdfName.DCTDECODE)) {
                                        //Get the raw bytes of the current image
                                        byte[] oldBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)imgObject);
                                        //Will hold bytes of the compressed image later
                                        byte[] newBytes;
                                        //Wrap a stream around our original image
                                        using (MemoryStream sourceMS = new MemoryStream(oldBytes)) {
                                            //Convert the bytes into a .Net image
                                            using (System.Drawing.Image oldImage = Bitmap.FromStream(sourceMS)) {
                                                //Shrink the image to 90% of the original
                                                using (System.Drawing.Image newImage = ShrinkImage(oldImage, 0.9f)) {
                                                    //Convert the image to bytes using JPG at 85%
                                                    newBytes = ConvertImageToBytes(newImage, 85);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        //Create a new iTextSharp image from our bytes
                                        iTextSharp.text.Image compressedImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(newBytes);
                                        //Kill off the old image
                                        PdfReader.KillIndirect(obj);
                                        //Add our image in its place
                                        stamper.Writer.AddDirectImageSimple(compressedImage, (PRIndirectReference)obj);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }

        //Standard image save code from MSDN, returns a byte array
        private static byte[] ConvertImageToBytes(System.Drawing.Image image, long compressionLevel) {
            if (compressionLevel < 0) {
                compressionLevel = 0;
            } else if (compressionLevel > 100) {
                compressionLevel = 100;
            }
            ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
            EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, compressionLevel);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                image.Save(ms, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }

        }
        //standard code from MSDN
        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format) {
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs) {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid) {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        //Standard high quality thumbnail generation from http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/04/02/resizing-images-without-loss-of-quality.aspx
        private static System.Drawing.Image ShrinkImage(System.Drawing.Image sourceImage, float scaleFactor) {
            int newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(sourceImage.Width * scaleFactor);
            int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(sourceImage.Height * scaleFactor);

            var thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailBitmap)) {
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                System.Drawing.Rectangle imageRectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                g.DrawImage(sourceImage, imageRectangle);
            }
            return thumbnailBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Concerning DPI, it's based on the size and scale of the image against the size of the page. So different parts of the same page could have different DPI.

Comment: Yes, that's effectively what happens. But nowhere in the PDF language can you say "make this image 300 DPI". Instead you say "here's a 500 pixel wide image, scale it by 10%".

Comment: @ChrisHaas all I am actually trying to do is get the pdf size down

Comment: Also with this method you will get white fragments where transparency was supposed to be

Comment: so I think the actual question is how to preserve the transparency when re-compressing the memory stream

Comment: @user1053237, if you want to shrink a PDF with iTextSharp then shrinking the images is the best way and this is how you do it. iTextSharp itself won't touch your images or apply any compression for you. (Okay, not technically correct, it will apply a degree of LOSSLESS compression but that doesn't affect already compressed data too much.) The sample above showed how to work with a JPG which obviously doesn't support transparency. You should be able to perform the same basic routine with PNGs but you'll need to switch encoders in `ConvertImageToBytes`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about iTextSharp, but you have to rewrite a PDF file if anything is changed, as it contains an xref table (index) with the exact file position of each object. This means if even one byte is added or removed, the PDF becomes corrupted.

Your best bet for recompressing the images is JBIG2 if they are B&W, or JPEG2000 otherwise, for which Jasper library will happily encode JPEG2000 codestreams for placement into PDF files at whatever quality you so desire.

If it were me I'd do it all from code without the PDF libraries. Just find all images (anything between `stream` and `endstream` after an occurance of `JPXDecode` (JPEG2000), `JBIG2Decode` (JBIG2) or `DCTDecode` (JPEG)) pull that out, reencode it with Jasper, then stick it back in again and update the xref table.

To update the xref table, find the positions of each object (starting `00001 0 obj`) and just update the new positions in the xref table. It's not too much work, less than it sounds. You might be able to get all the offsets with a single regular expression (I'm not a C# programmer, but in PHP it would be that simple.)

Then finally update the value of the `startxref` tag in the `trailer` with the offset of the beginning of the xref table (where it says `xref` in the file).

Otherwise you'll end up decoding the entire PDF and rewriting it all, which will be slow, and you might lose something along the way.

Comment: the issue comes in where you actually need to make sure the stream is not corrupt

Comment: Which stream, the image stream? Why would the stream be corrupt?

Comment: Well to actually get it properly in the first place I tried to save the parts between stream and endstream to a image file on the disk and it could not be opened. I am now just writing each line to a new pdf file and then checking if  I can get the line that contains the image into a memorystream or something

Comment: It sure can be opened if you save it correctly. There is a newline byte after the `stream` and before the `endstream`, you need to account for this and remove that from the variable before saving to file. Don't use a string trim function on it as that'll trim off some of the bytes that you want and corrupt the image. Then you just need to make sure you know what format it is. JPEG2000 embedded in codestream format without the full header, so the extension is .jpc, Jasper can process this. JPEGs (DCTDecode) should be normal.

Comment: If you can't open it from disk then keeping it in memory will NOT help. It is the same image. If it's corrupt in one it's corrupt in the other. If the image displays when you view the PDF, then the image can be extracted and saved to file. Your issue is probably with those newline bytes.

Comment: If the object says `/Filter /DCTDecode` then you extract everything between offsets of `stream` +7 and `endstream` -1 and save it to a file with extension `.jpg`. If it says `/Filter /JPXDecode` then do the same except extension `.jpc`. Then process it and put it back. If you change the format you'll also have to change the `/Filter` tag in the object, otherwise not. You WILL have to change the `/Length` tag, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Alasdair - Your comment about Jasper encoding JBIG2 and JPEG2000 images is interesting. So the library can do compression on those two formats? Do you have a link, or is it the [one here](http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/)?

Comment: Yes that one, but Jasper is only for JPEG2000 & JPEG formats. For JBIG2 you need jbig2enc & jbig2dec, for encoding and decoding respectively (all open source).

Answer (score 6):

There is an example on how to [find and replace images in an existing PDF](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=327) by the [creator of iText](http://www.lowagie.com/). It's actually a small excerpt from [his book](http://itextpdf.com/book/). Since it's in Java, here's a simple replacement:

```
public void ReduceResolution(PdfReader reader, long quality) {
  int n = reader.XrefSize;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    PdfObject obj = reader.GetPdfObject(i);
    if (obj == null || !obj.IsStream()) {continue;}

    PdfDictionary dict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
    PdfName subType = (PdfName)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(
      dict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)
    );
    if (!PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(subType)) {continue;}

    PRStream stream = (PRStream )obj;
    try {
      PdfImageObject image = new PdfImageObject(stream);
      PdfName filter = (PdfName) image.Get(PdfName.FILTER);
      if (
        PdfName.JBIG2DECODE.Equals(filter)
        || PdfName.JPXDECODE.Equals(filter)
        || PdfName.CCITTFAXDECODE.Equals(filter)
        || PdfName.FLATEDECODE.Equals(filter)
      ) continue;

      System.Drawing.Image img = image.GetDrawingImage();
      if (img == null) continue;

      var ll = image.GetImageBytesType();
      int width = img.Width;
      int height = img.Height;
      using (System.Drawing.Bitmap dotnetImg =
         new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img))
      {
        // set codec to jpeg type => jpeg index codec is "1"
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo codec =
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[1];
        // set parameters for image quality
        System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters eParams =
         new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
        eParams.Param[0] =
         new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(
           System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality
        );
        using (MemoryStream msImg = new MemoryStream()) {
          dotnetImg.Save(msImg, codec, eParams);
          msImg.Position = 0;
          stream.SetData(msImg.ToArray());
          stream.SetData(
           msImg.ToArray(), false, PRStream.BEST_COMPRESSION
          );
          stream.Put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
          stream.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
          stream.Put(PdfName.FILTER, filter);
          stream.Put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.DCTDECODE);
          stream.Put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(width));
          stream.Put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(height));
          stream.Put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, new PdfNumber(8));
          stream.Put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB);
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      // throw;
      // iText[Sharp] can't handle all image types...
    }
    finally {
// may or may not help      
      reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
    }
  }
}
```

You'll notice it's *only* handling JPEG. The logic is reversed (instead of explicitly handling only `DCTDECODE`/JPEG) so you can uncomment some of the ignored image types and experiment with the `PdfImageObject` in the code above. In particular, most of the `FLATEDECODE` images (.bmp, .png, and .gif) are represented as PNG (confirmed in the `DecodeImageBytes` method of the `PdfImageObject` source code). As far as I know, .NET does not support PNG encoding. There are some references to support this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418454/c-seeking-png-compression-algorithm-library) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922533/png-compression-in-net). You can try a stand-alone [PNG optimization executable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/png), but you also have to figure out how to set `PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT` and `PdfName.COLORSPACE` in the `PRStream`.

For completeness sake, since your question specifically asks about PDF compression, here's how you compress a PDF with iTextSharp:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(
  reader, YOUR-STREAM, PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5
);
stamper.Writer.CompressionLevel = 9;
int total = reader.NumberOfPages + 1;
for (int i = 1; i < total; i++) {
  reader.SetPageContent(i, reader.GetPageContent(i));
}
stamper.SetFullCompression();
stamper.Close();
```

You might also try and run the PDF through [PdfSmartCopy](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfSmartCopy.html)  to get the file size down. It removes redundant resources, but like the call to `RemoveUnusedObjects()` in the `finally` block, it may or may not help. That will depend on how the PDF was created.

IIRC iText[Sharp] doesn't deal well with `JBIG2DECODE`, so @Alasdair's suggestion looks good - if you want to take the time learning the Jasper library and using the brute-force approach.

Good luck.

**EDIT - 2012-08-17**, comment by @Craig:

To save the PDF after compressing the jpegs using the `ReduceResolution()` method above:

a. Instantiate a `PdfReader` object:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
```

b. Pass the `PdfReader` to the `ReduceResolution()` method above.

c. Pass the altered `PdfReader` to a `PdfStamper`. Here's one way using a `MemoryStream`:

```
// Save altered PDF. then you can pass the btye array to a database, etc
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
  using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
  }
  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Or you can use any other `Stream` if you don't need to keep the PDF in memory. E.g. use a `FileStream` and save directly to disk.

Comment: This is nice but how do you save the pdf once the you've compressed all the images. That bit of code is left out <sigh>.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried to implement it. But I get an error. Posted it as a seperate question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256195/rebuild-failed-using-pdf-compression

Comment: This worked and compressed my PDF by 90% - Thank you!

Comment: Writing to file part is not clear. When I write with code `PdfStamer(reader, new FileStream(@"C:\outputfile.pdf", FileMode.Create)` nothing changes. Meaning, file is still same. am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Intrigue, Can you mention your code section where you write the result from `ReduceResolution` to file? It isn't working for me, or I might be missing something.

Comment: super! It did compress the images in the pdf... I just changed this void to return a PdfReader, basically, I sent the Reader and get a Reader back... this time with images compressed

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are considering other libraries, but you can easily recompress existing images using [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (Disclaimer: I work for the company).

Here is some sample code:

```
static void RecompressExistingImages(string fileName, string outputName)
{
    using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(fileName))
    {
        foreach (PdfImage image in doc.Images)
            image.RecompressWithGroup4Fax();

        doc.Save(outputName);
    }
}
```

There are also `RecompressWithFlate`, `RecompressWithGroup3Fax`, `RecompressWithJpeg` and `Uncompress` methods.

The library will convert color images to bilevel ones if needed. You can specify deflate compression level, JPEG quality etc.

I am also ask you to think twice before using approach suggested by @Alasdair. If you are going to deal with PDF files that weren't created by you than the task is far more complex that it might seem.

To start with, there is great deal of images compressed by codecs other than `JPXDecode`, `JBIG2Decode` or `DCTDecode`. And PDF can also contain inline images.

PDF files saved using newer versions of standard (1.5 or newer) can contain cross-reference streams. It means that reading and updating such files is more complex than just finding/updating some numbers at the end of the file.

So, please, use a PDF library.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a library to do just that. It will also OCR the pdf's using Tesseract or Cuneiform and create searchable, compressed PDF files. It's a library that uses several open source projects (iTextsharp, jbig2 encoder, Aforge, muPDF#) to complete the task. You can check it out here http://hocrtopdf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to compress PDF is using gsdll32.dll (Ghostscript) and Cyotek.GhostScript.dll (wrapper):

```
public static void CompressPDF(string sInFile, string sOutFile, int iResolution)
    {
        string[] arg = new string[]
        {
            "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
            "-dNOPAUSE",
            "-dSAFER",
            "-dBATCH",
            "-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5",
            "-dDownsampleColorImages=true",
            "-dDownsampleGrayImages=true",
            "-dDownsampleMonoImages=true",
            "-sPAPERSIZE=a4",
            "-dPDFFitPage",
            "-dDOINTERPOLATE",
            "-dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0",
            "-dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0",
            "-dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0",
            "-dColorImageResolution=" + iResolution.ToString(),
            "-dGrayImageResolution=" + iResolution.ToString(),
            "-dMonoImageResolution=" + iResolution.ToString(),
            "-sOutputFile=" + sOutFile,
            sInFile
        };
        using(GhostScriptAPI api = new GhostScriptAPI())
        {
            api.Execute(arg);
        }
    }
```