# Rebuild failed using PDF compression

Tags: itext

Im trying to use the methods described bt `kuujinbo` here.
[PDF Compression with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740244/pdf-compression/8751517)

This is my code, and it results in this error:
"Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: PDF startxref not found."

```
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(output.ToArray());
            ReduceResolution(reader, 9);

            // Save altered PDF. then you can pass the btye array to a database, etc
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                {
                }

                document.Close();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=Produktark-{0}.pdf", myItem.Key));
                Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
            }
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: What is in the *output* variable in your code? The message seems to indicate that it is not a PDF, at least not a complete one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An exception stating *Rebuild failed: ...; Original message: ...* is thrown by iText only during `PdfReader` initialization, i.e. in your case in the line

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(output.ToArray());
```

and it indicates that the read data, i.e. `output.ToArray()`, does not constitute a valid PDF. You should write `output.ToArray()` to some file, too, and inspect it.

If you wonder why the message indicates that some ***Rebuild*** failed... you actually don't get the initial error but a follow-up one, the PDF digesting code has multiple blocks like this

```
try {
    read some part of the PDF;
} catch(Exception) {
    try {
        try to repair that part of the PDF and read it;
    } catch(Exception) {
        throw "Rebuild failed: ...; Original message: ...";
    }
}
```

In your case the part of interest was the cross reference table/stream and the issue was that the *PDF startxref* (a statement containing the offset of the cross reference start in the document) was *not found*.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
If I do like this:
´Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=Produktark-{0}.pdf", myItem.Key));
                Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());´ it works, the PDF is rendered normally. So something happens when I try to use the other code.

Comment: Just to be clear (and as @mkl said), your exception is being thrown on the first line of code you posted, correct? If that's the case, the code _after_ it isn't relevant, its the code that's _before_ it that we need.

Comment: *So something happens when I try to use the other code.* - The input you give to the reader is broken. That something is displayed when you return it to a PDF renderer in some browser does hardly prove anything as these renderers often are very forgiving. Thus: **You should write output.ToArray() to some file, too, and inspect it.**

Answer (score 2):

When I receive this error message it is caused by not closing the PDFStamper that I am using to edit the form fields.

```
Stamper.Close();
```

Must call before closing the PDF or will throw specified error.