# Bitmap PNG save without modifications

Tags: c#, image, gdi+

I am attempting to load a PNG image into a Bitmap and save it without modifications.

I tried something along these lines:

```
var png = Bitmap.FromFile("t_02.png");
png.Save("t_02_out.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I also tried:

```
var png = Bitmap.FromFile("t_02.png");
png.Save("t_02_out.png");
```

In either case, the original 233kb file procuded a 356kb image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is too much to explain with a lesser compression.  PNG supports a number of image formats that GDI+ won't reproduce.  You can tinker with PngBitmapEncoder if it is important, BitmapSource gives you more control over the PixelFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image in question is stored with the grey-scale color type. The specification describes:

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html

A pixel is then be stored as a single byte. `.NET` saves a PNG file as 32-bit regardless of pixel format.

The closest I got is using `AForge` grayscale filter and storing, which turns it into a palette storage.

The result is then much closer to the original, but due to the palet it is often still larger.

**Conclusion**: .NET image format support is terrible. I used `ImageMagic` to solve .NET incompetence.

Answer (score 2):

PNG is compressed format. You decompress on load and compress back on save. Result does not have to be the same exactly. The difference is in the fact that originally the image was compressed more efficiently than the compressor used by your code (or, you need to fine tune compressing options). In particular, if you used to save into PNG using popular graphic editor tools, you have options to specify compression level there and hence different output for the same picture.

Putting up useful links from comments:

- [How to specify compression level?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/700494-how-specify-compression-level-when-saving-loseless-pngs)
- [C#: Seeking PNG Compression algorithm/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418454/c-seeking-png-compression-algorithm-library)

Comment: also check these articels: [How to specify compression level?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/700494-how-specify-compression-level-when-saving-loseless-pngs) and [Seeking PNG compression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418454/c-seeking-png-compression-algorithm-library)